# Uniqueness of probability measure?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

During my first undergraduate course in probability, we defined a probability measure as a function $\mathbb P: S \to [0, 1] \subseteq \mathbb R$ such that, for all subsets $A$ of $S$ we have

> $0 \leq \mathbb P(A) \leq 1$
>
> $\mathbb P(S) = 1$
>
> If $\left\{A_k\right\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of pairwise disjoint subsets of $S$, then $\mathbb P\left( \displaystyle\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n \right) = \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb P(A_n)$

We referred to this axiomatic approach and the axioms above as "the axioms of probability". The exact definition of a sequence of pairwise disjoint subsets required $\begin{cases}A_k, A_j \subseteq S \\ j \neq k\end{cases} \implies A_j \cap A_k = \{\}$.

Now, we didn't say much about what sort of set $S$ had to be (we mentioned $S$ had to be a $\sigma$-field), but suppose a function satisfying the axioms of infinity for some set $S$ exists. Is this function then unique?

Comment: Nope.  There are typically many measures that can be defined on a measurable space.  As a really basic example, consider a single coin toss.  The corresponding $\sigma$-field consists of the sets $\{\emptyset, \{h\}, \{t\}, \{h,t\}\}$.  But the *measure* (or probability) of each set depends on the weighting of the coin.  If the coin is fair, we would get one measure.  If we have a trick coin that only ever comes up heads, we would get something else.

Comment: Here $S$ is not the $\sigma$-field, but $\wp(S)$ is the $\sigma$-field. For more info have a look at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"for all subsets $A$ of $S$.."

That actually reveals that $\mathbb P$ is **not** a function $S\to[0,1]$ (as you stated) but a function $\wp(S)\to[0,1]$, and this collection $\wp(S)$ is in this context a $\sigma$-field.

Formally we are dealing with [probability space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space#Definition) $\langle S,\wp(S),\mathbb P\rangle$.

Function $\mathbb P$ is not unique in general.

In non-trivial case there is a distinct function $\mathbb Q:\wp(S)\to[0,1]$ having the same properties (or fulfilling the same axioms of probability in your terminology).

To convince yourself try to find two distinct probabilities on  [measurable space](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MeasurableSpace.html) $\langle\{0,1\},\wp(\{0,1\})\rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

No, in general many probability measures can be built on the same $\sigma$-field. For example a loaded dice and a fair dice represent two probability measures on the same set $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$

For the fair dice, you have
$$P(1) = P(2) = \cdots = P(6) = \frac{1}{6}$$

and for a loaded dice, you could have for example

$$P(1) = P(2) = \cdots = P(5) = \frac{1}{7}\qquad P(6)=\frac{2}{7}$$

For a subset such as $A = \{2, 3, 6\}$, you have $P(A) = \frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{2}$ for the fair dice and
$P(A) = \frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{2}{7}=\frac{4}{7}$ for the loaded dice.